# For line 19, it keeps saying [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, class, decimal, overflow

The problem I keep getting is on line 19 `k = Decimal(e**(k2-k1))`

I've already set decimal precision to 8 and max of E to 200. Why does it still give me `[<class 'decimal.overflow'>]` ?

Here is my code:

```
from math import log
from math import e
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 8
getcontext().Emax = 200

Ea = range(0,161,5)
Temp = [700,730,760,790,810,840,910,1000]
Yi = [0.011,0.035,0.105,0.343,0.789,2.17,20.0,145]
R = 0.008314
A = 1.1*10**12

for a in Ea:
    kvalues = []
    for x in Temp:
        k1 = (-a/R*x)
        k2 = (log(A,e))
        #k = e**(log(A,e)-(-a/R*x))
        k = Decimal(e**(k2-k1))
        kvalues.append(k)

    sum = 0
    index = 0
    for yi in Yi:
        sum = sum + (yi - kvalues[index])**2
        index = index + 1
    print(sum, a)
```

Comment: This is what's *supposed* to happen if `Emax` is exceeded; see [`decimal.Overflow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Overflow). You can try using [`decimal.Clamped`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Clamped) to keep the exponent below `Emax`.

Comment: You might have better luck the [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) module. Here's its [pypi project link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mpmath/1.0.0)

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to solve this (admittedly, quite brute forcefully) by increasing the Emax to 900,000.